# Android Kotlin - RecyclerView - get position of recycled item

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Well as the title says, I need a listener that gives me the position of the item which was recycled.

So far I only found how to get the holder of the recycled item:

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)  
}
```

and I don't get why it doesn't also return the damn position of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use either of the methods according to your use case to get the position of the view to be recycled to create the new view.

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)  

    holder.layoutPosition

    holder.absoluteAdapterPosition

    holder.bindingAdapterPosition
}
```

**holder.layoutPosition**: Returns the position of the ViewHolder in terms of the latest layout pass.

**holder.absoluteAdapterPosition**: Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder with respect to the RecyclerView's Adapter.

**holder.bindingAdapterPosition** Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder with respect to the Adapter that bound it.

Comment: It look like holder.layoutPosition works fine, thanks! adapterPosition is deprecated though

Comment: if the solution helped please do upvote as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tag` of the `view` to complete

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HostingAndAdditionalHolder, position: Int) 
    {
        ...
        holder.binding.cb.tag = position
        ...
    }
```

Set up the listener when creating the view. In the code below, I set up the listener for cb.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): HostingAndAdditionalHolder {
        return HostingAndAdditionalSettingsItemViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        ).run {
            cb.setOnClickListener(checkOnClickListener)
            HostingAndAdditionalHolder(this)
        }
    }
```

This is my listener code

```kotlin
private val checkOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
        view.tag.let {
            if (it is Int) it else null
        }?.let {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why click listener? It doesn't suppose to listen to a click/tap but just to notify as soon as an item gets recycled and telling the position of it